# Slow adoption of C99

Tags: c, standards, c99, c11

I have lately looked at some pages describing adoption of C standard and I was terrified by the fact that C99 (which was created 15 years ago!) is not yet fully supported. Most of the compilers (if not all) does not support full C99 and we already have C11. Does it mean that those standards are dead or ignored or is it not worth to invest in C anymore?

Comment: If you are to become a seasoned developer one day, MS lousiness should not surprise you - it is as normal as the sky being blue or water being wet, if anything, it should surprise you if/when MS didn't do something lousy for a change :D

Comment: Most compilers actually have some sort of c99 support. Even MSVC introduced some c99 support last year.

Answer (score 2):

The big C compilers like gcc and clang support C99 (and mostly C11) without problems. Only Microsoft decided they wouldn't develop C99 support for Visual Studio, but instead work more on C++.

Comment: Hasn't Visual Studio 2013 (incompletely) adopted C99?

Comment: @pmg They implemented some more features, but not so many that i would call it supporting c99.